# Selecting distinct row of many database based on date field

Tags: mysql, sql

Sorry for the title. Hard to figure out an exact wording. So I've got a MySQL database with the structure of an ID, Name, and Date which works for events firing. I've got many events that go off periodically throughout the day, meaning some may be showing at certain times and not at other times. Each fired event is a new row, with an ID being the primary key and an indicator of the specific row, the Name being the name or creator or originator of the event, and the Date being a timestamp of when the event occurred.

My problem is that there are a lot of values of Name, and I'd like to find events which occurred within a certain time period, but not in a different time period. So any event Name which shows up in range 3pm-4pm but not in 5pm-6pm. Not worried on the timestamp part, just wondering if there's a way to word a statement to come to the conclusion I'm looking for.

So basically, I'd like to select a distinct Name where rows exist with a Date between w and x, and where rows do not exist between y and z

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you could use a subquery to select all the rows for 5-6pm, then select all the rows between 3-4pm minus the rows of your subquery:

```
--3-4pm
SELECT Name
FROM TableName
WHERE Date > 'YYYY/mm/dd' AND Date < 'YYYY/mm/dd'
AND ID NOT IN ( 
                --5-6pm
                SELECT ID
                FROM TableName
                WHERE Date > 'YYYY/mm/dd' AND Date < 'YYYY/mm/dd'
              )
```

Comment: Thanks, this solved it. Specifically the `NOT IN` part was what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for names that have records between 3pm and 4pm and none between 5pm and 6pm. You want a list of names as a result. So you'll aggregate your data such as to get a row per name (`GROUP BY name`). Then you use `HAVING` to filter the data.

```
select name
from mytable
group by name
having sum( extract(hour from date) = 15 ) > 0
   and sum( extract(hour from date) = 17 ) = 0;
```

This makes use of MySQL's boolean logic where TRUE = 1 and FALSE = 0.